# Need a web analytics report that shows pages with 0 hits

Tags: 2010

We are looking for a web analytics report that will show us a list of pages with 0 hits within a certain date range in SP 2010.

We already have web analytics turned on but it only shows pages that have hits. We need to see pages with 0 hits to clean them out.

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?